# How do I manipulate Dataframes inside a list after using Split function in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, memory, split

So, I have a huge set of data and after using split to make it into smaller ones I need to manipulate them all with the same process (create columns, sort, sum... this kind of things). After that I will stack them all together again and export. I am doing this to save memory, I read it is a possibility.

My code is as follows: (I define all variables before)

```
df <- read.csv(paste(path,"//",file,".","csv",sep=""), FALSE , ";")
df <- setNames(df, c("BUCKET","FECHA", "DATO"))

df1 <- split(df, f = df$BUCKET)

df1$FECHA1=paste(substr(df1$FECHA, 1, 4),substr(df1$FECHA, 5, 6), substr(df1$FECHA, 7, 8), sep = "-")
```

I also do some other manipulations, but specifically in this one I just rearrange the FECHA column content, which has dates (20220101 format into 2022-01-01).

The reason I use split is that later I dont have enough memory to work with my original data.frame, so I imagined I could split and work each one individually, but I can´t make it work. Instead of creating a column on each subset of my original dataframe inside the list, it just makes a FECHA1 character [0] at the end.

Is this that I am trying to do even possible? if so, how? Is there any other way to work with big sets of dataframe?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If `FECHA1` is a date in the ymd format, instead of `paste/substr`, use `lubridate::ymd(df1$FECHA1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can transform each sub-data.frame in the list with a `lapply` loop.

The anonymous function must end by returning the changed object `DF`.

```
df1 <- lapply(df1, \(DF) {
  DF[["FECHA1"]] <- lubridate::ymd(DF[["FECHA"]])
  DF
})
```

And the same for other transformations. If the transformations are too complex, write them as functions and call those functions in a `lapply` loop.

Like above, don't forget to return the changed object `DF`.

```
df1 <- lapply(df1, \(DF) {
  d <- DF[["FECHA1"]]
  DF[["CUTPOINT"]] <- cut(d, "2022-01-01", labels = c("Other year", "Current year"))
  DF
})
```